# Adding a logo in html5 blank template

Tags: logo

I have installed html5 blank template and created subtheme also. I need to add a logo?I have added the image in media option in admin panel but how should I use as a logo?I am unable to find any option to attach logo file in admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a logo is not part of the functionality of the html5 blank template as far as I know. You will have to access your theme folder and change the path to your own logo. It comes with a logo.svg files, which is referenced in the header.php file. Look for the logo and substitute it with your own file.

Comment: I have installed `theme logo` plugin, and add an image in media in admin panel. Now how can I change the logo?have u used theme logo plugin?

Comment: Ok got it..I didnt copy the correct location in theme logo plugin

Comment: I'm glad you solved it.